# Arduino UNO seems to be dead

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have two Arduino UNO devices. For this purpose I user the blink example. If I connect the first arduino and upload the script, the LED at pin 13 starts blinking  with an interval of one second as expected. Now when I attach the second Arduino, the LED 'L' starts flashing (a short flash, one second off, and s short flash again). It starts doing that immidiately after plugging in the USB cable.

If I upload the blink example script, I receive the following (having 'show verbose output during upload switched on):

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 15 2015 at 19:59:58
Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

Using Port                    : COM5
Using Programmer              : arduino
Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
and so on and so on
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9f
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

It seems like the board is dead. Someone with a good idea?
Thanks a bunch! Eduard

Comment: Perhaps the second arduino installed another usb to serial driver at a different port as COM5. But that's just a wild guess. Your programmer should be AVRISP mkII. You can check both (port and programmer) in the tools menu. (as you sure know ;-) ) Do you use a different USB port on your computer? That could also be a problem. If nothing works, I would agree and say that the arduino or at least the usb to serial part of the arduino is dead. If the MCU is in a socket (i.e not soldered) you can change it to see if the MCU is dead.

Comment: Peter Paul, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly everything you say was checked and fine. Both boards are equal and appear on the same COM5 (as I use the same USB port on the computer). Selected programmer, board and port are correct. The MCU is soldered on an arduino board.

Comment: Just one more idea: Perhaps the bootloader on the "dead" Arduino is damaged. You can reburn it with your working Arduino if you configure it as a ISP by using the ICSP header on the "dead" Arduino board. Here are som links: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUnoSMD (section Programming) and https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP. Hope this helps. If the ICSP does not work then, I would say the (soldered) AVR chip had been gone forever. :-(. And I forgott: You can also program your bootloader with your Arduino IDE.